# Angular2 passing function results to child component - "this.bar is not a function"

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to pass a function data through to a child, but all the answers on SO is from Angular2 in (alfa/beta) and I do not know if my problem comes from the fact that things have changed since the official release. I have tried every answer on SO, but it does not seem to get rid of my error, which is "this.bar is not a function"

For now I am just trying to pass a simple string through with a function:

**Parent component:**

```
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
 foo() {
    return "This is a parent func stream value";
  }
}
```

**Parent HTML**

```
<child [bar]="foo()"></child>
```

**Child Component**

```
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
@Input() bar : Function;

ngOnInit() {
  this.bar();
}
```

I don't see the problem, please help me see!

**Edit**

The "Function" type in the code above is still colored white in my editor, which bothered me, but as soon as I paste code below my component like in the example below, the same "Function" turns blue, like the other types in my code, so I am trying to figure out why this is...

**Child Component**

```
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
@Input() bar : Function;  //The word "Function" here is white when it should be blue

ngOnInit() {
  this.bar();
}
}

@Input() bar: Function // This word "Function" is blue like it should be
  functionResult: any;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.functionResult = this.bar();
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`foo()` is really not a function. It evaluates to the return value of the function call. Your input `bar` expects a function as its type.

You should try to do it like `<child [bar]="foo"></child>`

**Edit**
See [working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4SibER06ZPNw8OrrLXEB)

Comment: Thanks for the plunker, I see that it works, but when I change my code like yours it gives the same issue. My code REALLY does not like that bar function...

Comment: Ok, I have seen something strange now by sheer luck. I copied and pasted your plunker code below mine to view it "side by side", and then I saw that suddenly the "Function" type of your code (at the bottom of my code) is highlighted blue, just like the other types that are in my code. But the "Function" type in my code in just white, which bothered me form the beginning. I will update my code above to show you what I mean. If you have any ideas why this it, I am all ears...

Comment: Can you create a plunker that reproduces your problem?

Comment: I have removed the brackets from the `this.bar()` line, and then the error goes away, but the result is "function () { return "This is a parent func stream value; } Why do you think that as soon as I add the brackets back, I get the error? (I get the same result with you punker if you remove the brackets)

Comment: Again, it will really help to understand the problem if you post a plunker that demonstrates it

Comment: **Ok I got it**, I used the <child> tags a few times in my parent template, but only added the [bar]="foo" to one of them cause I wanted the result only on one occasion, but now that I have added the `[bar]="foo"` to every tag, I get the correct result and no error.

Comment: Thanks for all your help and patience!!